# How should I approach this ivp problem with two differentiation about x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, integrating-factor

The question given is as followed:

> $$x dy - y dx - (1-x²)dx = 0,  \\ y(1)=1$$

How should I approach this question? I tried to start this problem by finding an integrating factor but what should I do when 2 dx appears on the equation?

Answer (score 1):

$$xdy = (1+y-x^2)dx \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = -x+\frac1x + \frac yx \implies \frac{dy}{dx} \color{blue}{- \frac{1}{x}}y = \color{green}{\frac1x-x}$$

$$\color{blue}{IF} = e^{\int\color{blue}{\frac{-1}{x}}dx}  = e^{-\ln x} = \color{blue}{\frac 1x}$$

Now,

$$\color{blue}{IF} \cdot y = \int \color{green}{\left(\frac1x-x\right)}\color{blue}{IF} dx+c \implies \frac yx = \int\left(\frac 1{x^2} -1\right)dx +c$$

Could you proceed further?

Comment: proceeding further, do you get the following general solution? $$ y=x(-x- \frac{1}{x}+c) \    $$ with c=3?

Answer (score 1):

$$x dy - y dx - (1-x²)dx = 0, y(1)=1$$
$$x dy - y dx - (1-x²)dx = 0$$
Divide by $x^2$ 
$$ \left (\dfrac {x dy - y dx }{x^2} \right)- \dfrac {(1-x²)}{x^2}dx  = 0$$
$$d \left (\dfrac yx \right)+dx - \dfrac {1}{x^2}dx = 0$$
Integrate.

Comment: Thank you for your help @LostInSpace! Do you get the general solution as $$ y=x(-x- \frac{1}{x}+c) \    $$, with c=3?

Comment: $c=3$  I get $y=3x-x^2-1$ yes that's correct @Santi

Comment: Thank you @LostInSpace! The problem is, to verify the particular solution I tried to differentiate both sides $$ y=3x-x^2-1 $$ but I didn't get the equation given at first. Why would it be?

Comment: Differentiate you get the same equation $y'=3-2x$ and $y=3x-x^2-1$ plug that in your equation $ y'-{ \frac{1}{x}}y = {\frac1x-x}$ @Santi You should get an equality

Comment: I tried it again and I got it @LostInSpace! Thank you

Comment: You're welcomed. @Santi